# can i use flink rocksDB state backend with local file system?

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I am exploring using Flink rocksDb state backend, the documentation seems to imply i can use a regular file system such as: `file:///data/flink/checkpoints`, but the code javadoc only mentions hdfs or s3 option here.

I am wondering if it's possible to use local file system with flink rocksdb backend, thanks!

Flink docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/state_backends.html#the-rocksdbstatebackend

Flink code: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-state-backends/flink-statebackend-rocksdb/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/contrib/streaming/state/RocksDBStateBackend.java#L175

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not do that!

With this path you configure the directory into which Flink writes checkpoints. A checkpoint is a copy of your application state that is used to restore the application state in case of a failure such as a machine failure. The path must point to a persistent and remote storage to be able to read the checkpoint in case that a process was killed ore a machine died. If a checkpoint was written to the local filesystem of a machine that failed, you would not be able to recover the job and restore the state.

However, you can write the checkpoint to a local path if this is a mount point of an NFS (or any other remote storage) that can be mounted from other machines as well.